# EPPlus cells not updated after number format

Tags: c#, epplus

Im trying to change number format with epplus in excel to this format ([h]:mm:ss), and it seems to change the cells format correctly. But the cells value doesnt update after the format...

As the picture shows the correct way of the text should be like the first cell on the picture. It works if I click on the cells and presses enter again[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAmsB.png)

```
var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(filename);

var tableRange = sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(list);
var table = sheet.Tables.GetFromRange(tableRange);
package.Save();
```

NumberFormat

```
[EpplusTableColumn(Order = 2, NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss")]
public string timeWorked { get; set; }
```

In the end, I want to use the SUM function in excel to calculate the total timeworked, but it doesnt work when the cells doesnt change to the format I have sat for it

Comment: Can you provide part of the code where you set the format to `[h]:mm:ss`?

Comment: @RandomSlav Uploaded picture

Comment: Please don´t add images of code. Code in images cannot be copied and tested. Please include the code properly formated in your question.

Comment: @burnsi Okay thanks for the tip, I have changed it to code instead of pictures

Comment: Don't use `string` to store dates. Use `DateTime` or `TimeSpan`. Excel has specific types for numbers and dates. `string` values have no format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, change type from `string` to `TimeSpan`

```
public TimeSpan TimeWorked { get; set; } = new TimeSpan(2, 18, 19);
```

Secondly, set `printHeader` to `true`

```
var tableRange = sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(actors, true);
```

*For some reason column when using `EpplusTableColumn` attribute headers need to be included in excel otherwise cell formatting doesn't work. I'm not sure if it's a bug or am I missing something.*

*Would love if someone can give me more explanation.*

If you really don't want headers to show there is a workaround. **Before** saving remove first row from excel.

```
sheet.DeleteRow(1);
package.Save();
```